# Extract all unsubscribed Contacts from child BU

Tags: marketing-cloud

How can I extract all unsubscribed Contacts (or at least their emails) from a child business unit? Using queries with `_subscribers` does not work and a Tracking Extract has a date range limit.

Comment: Why does  the _subscribers data view not work? Are you performing the query in the child BU or the parent?

Comment: The query has to be performed in the child BU as each  BU has independent preferences.

Comment: You need to add ‘ent.’ To the data view ie ent._subscribers

Comment: @Data_Kid I tried this and it brings back all the subs, when I try it without `ent` it brings back only 5% of my subscribers.